# Small space between ImageView and (Constraint)Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout, with a ConstraintLayout as the root. My problem is at the LinearLayout at the bottom of this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flowBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_workorderflow_bar_2"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bt_nextpage" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bt_previouspage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/backText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/textTint"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/backArrow"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/textTint"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/nextArrow"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see from the XML code, I have an ImageView on top of a ConstraintLayout and I'm getting the following effect:

[image]

There is a small space (probably around 1px) between the ImageView and the Layout. Can anyone explain to me why it is like it is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Does your image contains those little squares?

Comment: Yes it does, it also contains the white fill under those squares (until the space).

Comment: Are you sure that the 1px gap isn't in the image?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that.

Comment: Your layout has width of 0. Is the linearlayout inside another ContraintLayout?

Comment: Yes, it's inside the root ConstraintLayout. Above this LinearLayout there is another ConstraintLayout (thats the dark blue color).

Comment: Not sure how your whole layout looks like, but ConstraintLayout was meant to remove nesting of multiple views (improve performance), so that you can have flat view hierarchy.